# Getting the exact text that is shown in my ListView. Help!

Tags: c#, listview

I have this method:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            ListViewItem selectedFile = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            label7.Text = selectedFile.ToString();
            string selectedFileLocation = selectedFile.Tag.ToString();

            PlaySoundFile(selectedFileLocation);
        }                
    }
```

The result is this:

[image]

How can I retrieve the **exact** text that is selected in the ListView? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label7.Text = selectedFile.Text;
```